Change the Find Contacts search results using Default Contact Search Profile
So I want to change the default view when for search results when I use Find Contacts.
It appears I should be able to do this by setting the Default Contact Search Profile (ADMINISTER > CUSTOM DATA AND SCREENS > SEARCH PREFERENCES).
However the issue I have, is that I can not create a profile that shows any thing other than LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME. Regardless of what fields I add to the profile, only lastname,firstname show up in results. (see attached screenshot)
Even if I select the pre-defined "Name and Address" profile that came with civi, it will only display the same lastname,firstname and there is no address column.
So I guess my question is, what am doing wrong with my profile that is not allowing it to be used to display the find contacts search results?


Make sure you have Visibility set to public and Results Column? field checked.


Yes, thank you, that was what I was missing!
